# Deploying the MULE in LifeRay

Tags: mule

I have configured one MULE application. I want this application to be a portlet in a LIFERAY.
 How can I achieve this.
  Can I export the MULE application's WAR and deploy it LIFERAY or is there any plug-ins available to integrate the MULE with LIFERAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one plug-in is available in liferay CMIS Cloud connector which is use to integrate Liferay with Mule ESB

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a Liferay specific Mule plug-in. Your best option is to embed your Mule application in a web application and deploy its WAR in the same container that hosts your Liferay server.